# Why doesn't my code for sorting list by frequency work?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I was trying to sort a list of number by their frequency, but when I try asserting, it didn't work.

So here is my code:

```
def frequency_sorting(numbers):
    return sorted(numbers,key=numbers.count,reverse=True)
```

And here is the assert that doesn't work

```
assert frequency_sorting([3, 4, 11, 13, 11, 4, 4, 7, 3]) == [4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 11, 11, 7, 13]
```

When I tried directly with the value the output was as follow:

```
[4, 4, 4, 3, 11, 11, 3, 13, 7]
```

I tried looking at others solution and I found the following that worked:

```
sorted(sorted(numbers), key=numbers.count, reverse=True)
```

Why does this work and not my code? What is the difference between the 2 codes?
I don't understand why the first one doesn't work.

Comment: The difference is `sorted`. Can you see the difference?

Comment: Because you are sorting by the *frequency*, the value is being ignored, and Python `sorted` is stable

Comment: The sort is stable, so if values have the same count, they will appear in thei original order: 3, 11, 11, then 3 have the same count of 2.

Comment: As an aside, `key=numbers.count` is **highly highly** inefficient. It forces sorting to be O(N**2). Don't do that

Comment: Thank you everyone. I know understand the difference between the 2 codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`11` and `3` are both present twice, and your sorting function doesn't give a way to break ties. Since Python's sorting is stable, if A comes before B in the input list, and A and B have the same comparison key, A will also come before B in the output of `sorted`.

In your case, sorting the list before passing it to `frequency_sorting` orders your list numerically. And since sorting is stable, when you run *that* list through your `frequency_sorting` function, the result will still be in order.

If you want to do this more efficiently, you can use `Counter` to count your numbers with a O(n) algorithm. Sorting and list extension are *not* O(1), but they're still more efficient than running `numbers.count` on every number in the list.

```
from collections import Counter

def frequency_sorting(numbers):
    counted = Counter(sorted(numbers))

    result = []
    for number, count in counted.most_common():
        result.extend([number] * count)

    return result

assert frequency_sorting([3, 4, 11, 13, 11, 4, 4, 7, 3]) == [4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 11, 11, 7, 13]
```

Answer (score 0):

What sorted does in internally sort the list according to the key specified

so essentially
sorted(numbers,key=numbers.count,reverse=True)

This is trying to not sort

```
numbers
>>
[3, 4, 11, 13, 11, 4, 4, 7, 3]
```

but actually sort

```
[numbers.count(x) for x in numbers]
>>[2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2]
```

where 2 corresponds to both 11 and 3, so sort doesn't care if the original value was 11 or 3 as long as this array gets sorted

[EDIT]

Hence the solution that works using sorted would be using sorted twice

```
sorted(sorted(numbers), key=numbers.count, reverse=True)
```